# Can I use script to decide the creation of table in flywaydb?

Tags: flyway

In flywaydb, I need to decide if the table already exists in the database. If so, skip creation of the table, or else create. I tried this and I get weird errors in the logs..

**Sql in the migrations folder**

```
declare
    c number:=0;
begin
    SELECT count(*) into c
      FROM dba_tables where table_name = 'sample_table' AND OWNER='TDS_INT';  

      if c = 0 then
          CREATE TABLE TDS_INT.sample_table
            (  
                sample_id               NUMBER(19)          ,
                WORK_ORDER_ID           VARCHAR2(20)        CONSTRAINT TBT895_CK_010_N NOT NULL,
                TASK_TYPE               VARCHAR2(8)         CONSTRAINT TBT895_CK_015_N NOT NULL,
                LEAD_TIME               VARCHAR2(20)        CONSTRAINT TBT895_CK_025_N NOT NULL,
                LAST_MODIFIED_DATE      DATE                CONSTRAINT TBT895_CK_030_N NOT NULL,
                LAST_MODIFIED_USERID    VARCHAR2(8)         CONSTRAINT TBT895_CK_035_N NOT NULL

            );     
        end if;
end;
```

**Error logs:**

```
    Migrating schema "ASAP" to version 2.1 - create sample table
DEBUG: Executing SQL: declare
        c number:=0;
begin
        SELECT count(*) into c
          FROM dba_tables where table_name = 'sample_table' AND OWNER='TDS_INT';


          if c = 0 then
                  CREATE TABLE TDS_INT.sample_table
                        (
                                sample_id                               NUMBER(1
9)              ,
                                WORK_ORDER_ID                   VARCHAR2(20)
        CONSTRAINT TBT895_CK_010_N NOT NULL,
                                TASK_TYPE                           VARCHAR2(8)
                CONSTRAINT TBT895_CK_015_N NOT NULL,
                                LEAD_TIME                               VARCHAR2
(20)            CONSTRAINT TBT895_CK_025_N NOT NULL,
                                LAST_MODIFIED_DATE              DATE
                CONSTRAINT TBT895_CK_030_N NOT NULL,
                                LAST_MODIFIED_USERID    VARCHAR2(8)
CONSTRAINT TBT895_CK_035_N NOT NULL

                        );
                end if;
end;

DEBUG: Rolling back transaction...
DEBUG: Transaction rolled back
ERROR: Migration of schema "ASAP" to version 2.1 - create sample table failed! P
lease restore backups and roll back database and code!
DEBUG: MetaData table "ASAP"."schema_version" successfully updated to reflect ch
anges
ERROR: Unexpected error
org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.FlywaySqlScriptException:
Migration V2_1__create_sample_table.sql failed
----------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 65000
Error Code : 6550
Message    : ORA-06550: line 8, column 5:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:

   begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
   close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe
The symbol "lock was inserted before "CREATE" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 9, column 4:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:

   . , @ in <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> partition subpartition
ORA-06550: line 11, column 36:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CONSTRAINT" when expecting one of the followi
ng:

   := ) , not null default external character
The symbol "," was substituted for "CONSTRAINT" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 12, column 35:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CONSTRAINT" when expecting one of the followi
ng:

   := ) , not null default external character
The symbol "," was substituted for "CONSTRAINT" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 13, column 33:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CONSTRAINT" when expecting one of the followi
ng:

   := ) , not null default external character
The symbol "," was substituted for "CONSTRAINT" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 14, column 34:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CONSTRAINT" when expecting one of the followi
ng:

   := . ( ) , @ % not null range with default external character
The symbol "," was substituted for "CONSTRAINT" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 15, column 40:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CONSTRAINT" when expecting one of the followi
ng:

   := ) , not null default external character
The symbol "," was substituted for "CONSTRAINT" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 18, column 3:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function package pragma procedure subtype type use
   <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> form
   current cursor
Location   : C:/Project/Tools/Migrations/V2_1__create_sample_table.sql (C:\Proje
ct\Tools\Migrations\V2_1__create_sample_table.sql)
Line       : 1
Statement  : declare
        c number:=0;
begin
        SELECT count(*) into c
          FROM dba_tables where table_name = 'sample_table' AND OWNER='TDS_INT';


          if c = 0 then
                  CREATE TABLE TDS_INT.sample_table
                        (
                                sample_id                               NUMBER(1
9)              ,
                                WORK_ORDER_ID                   VARCHAR2(20)
        CONSTRAINT TBT895_CK_010_N NOT NULL,
                                TASK_TYPE                           VARCHAR2(8)
                CONSTRAINT TBT895_CK_015_N NOT NULL,
                                LEAD_TIME                               VARCHAR2
(20)            CONSTRAINT TBT895_CK_025_N NOT NULL,
                                LAST_MODIFIED_DATE              DATE
                CONSTRAINT TBT895_CK_030_N NOT NULL,
                                LAST_MODIFIED_USERID    VARCHAR2(8)
CONSTRAINT TBT895_CK_035_N NOT NULL

                        );
                end if;
end;


        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.SqlScript.execute(SqlScript.java
:117)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationExecutor.execute(
SqlMigrationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.doMigrate(DbMigrate.java
:352)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.access$1100(DbMigrate.ja
va:47)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$4.doInTransaction(DbMigr
ate.java:308)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(Tran
sactionTemplate.java:72)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.applyMigration(DbMigrate
.java:305)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.access$1000(DbMigrate.ja
va:47)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$2.doInTransaction(DbMigr
ate.java:230)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$2.doInTransaction(DbMigr
ate.java:173)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(Tran
sactionTemplate.java:72)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrate(DbMigrate.java:1
73)
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:959)
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:917)
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1373)
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:917)
        at org.flywaydb.commandline.Main.executeOperation(Main.java:139)
        at org.flywaydb.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:102)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 8, column 5:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:

   begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
   close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe
The symbol "lock was inserted before "CREATE" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 9, column 4:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:

   . , @ in <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> partition subpartition
ORA-06550: line 11, column 36:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CONSTRAINT" when expecting one of the followi
ng:

   := ) , not null default external character
The symbol "," was substituted for "CONSTRAINT" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 12, column 35:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CONSTRAINT" when expecting one of the followi
ng:

   := ) , not null default external character
The symbol "," was substituted for "CONSTRAINT" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 13, column 33:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CONSTRAINT" when expecting one of the followi
ng:

   := ) , not null default external character
The symbol "," was substituted for "CONSTRAINT" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 14, column 34:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CONSTRAINT" when expecting one of the followi
ng:

   := . ( ) , @ % not null range with default external character
The symbol "," was substituted for "CONSTRAINT" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 15, column 40:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CONSTRAINT" when expecting one of the followi
ng:

   := ) , not null default external character
The symbol "," was substituted for "CONSTRAINT" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 18, column 3:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function package pragma procedure subtype type use
   <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> form
   current cursor

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:439)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:395)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:802)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:436)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:194)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:1000
)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStateme
nt.java:1307)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.ja
va:1882)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1847)

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrap
per.java:301)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate.executeStatement(Jd
bcTemplate.java:238)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.SqlScript.execute(SqlScript.java
:114)
        ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Flyway will execute each migration script and give you no hint to execute it or not. It depends on you to write the correct code to create the table or not. But if you have flyway to create and migrate your database than you should not have the situation to check existing of table. 
I can only think in situation to migrate from different version without Flyway support to a Flyway managed database.

Last time I had this problem (not with oracle) I used two small migration script. First script contains a real SQL procedure with the check off table exist and creation. The second script contains the deletion of the SQL procedure.

Comment: Thank you, we decided to move away from it and use Liquibase, liquibase is more mature in that matters.